Is there a way to set up a unique notification for a button in a widget so as to not get overwritten by when a second widget is created?
I've been doing some Android Widgets tutorials, and learning Kotlin at the same time.
I have successfully set up a widget with a button and a notification for that button which does some code and then updates the widget.
When trying to add a second widget, and trying to add another intent notification, I see that the first button now updates the second widget. It's as if the notification I set up in the second button updates and overwrites the first notification.
I am using the standard PendingIntent.getBroadcast([..]_UPDATE or _IMMUTABLE)  functionality, with a new intent created each time, for setting up the notification firing.
I haven't had a chance to test, should I remove the IMMUTABLE flag from my code?
I can provide some code tomorrow.
Edit: Some code, as promised:
val intent = Intent(context, Counter::class.java).also {
        it.setAction(MY_ACTION)
        it.putExtra("appWidgetId", appWidgetId)
    }

    // Get the layout for the widget and attach an onClick listener to
    // the button.
    views.apply {
        setOnClickPendingIntent(
            R.id.button, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        )
    }


You probably are missing the unique ID with the PendingIntent, but a [mcve] would go a long way towards helping us determine that.

I found another post today which says that it might need a different request code, action or data to make it unique. I can't change the action, but I can maybe change the data to make it unique.

PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

See that 0? That needs to be a distinct value for each of your buttons in your app widget's RemoteViews.
